# Problema requisição - Phonegap + Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache-cordova, mobile

estava fazendo um teste para testar o phonegap, porém eu não estou conseguindo fazer um requisição Ajax no app, mas a requisição funciona no browser.

```
$( "#botaoBusca" ).click(function(){

var cep = $( "#cep" ).val();

$.getJSON('https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+cep+'/json/?callback=?', function(data) {

var endereco =
   { rua    : data.logradouro,
     cidade : data.localidade,
     uf     : data.uf
   };

$( "#endereco" ).text("Você mora na "+endereco.rua+", "+endereco.cidade+" - "+endereco.uf);

});
});
```

HTML:

```
</head>
 <body>
   <div class="container text-center">
   <div class="row">
    <h1>Olá, AJAX</h1>

            <label>Digite o seu cep:</label>   
            <input id="cep" type="text" pattern="\d{8}" maxlength="8"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="botaoBusca" type="button">Buscar</button>    

            <h3 id="endereco"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
```

Obrigado

Comment: Por padrão, o PhoneGap possui um "bloqueio" ao acesso de paginas da internet pelo aplicativo. Mas para quem necessita desse acesso, ele na sua própria documentação possui um guia explicando como resolver isso. Segue o link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#supported-cordova-platforms

Answer (score -1):

Você colocou a permissão para o aplicativo usar internet ? 
Caso não tenha colocado o android não deixa o aplicativo usar recursos de internet, assim seu código não vai se comunicar com o servidor.

E se você estiver usando o Cordova 4.1+ ( ou superior ) poder ser algum problema com o WhiteList, confere ai pra ver se ele está instalado.